# simple database in SQlite doesn't work

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I'm new to programming, following a tutorial and here is my problem:

After downloading SQlite3 I created an empty file "test.db" in c:\sqlite

Then, in C:\Python27 I created "dbcreate.py":

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("create table films(title text, year text, director text)")
print("table created")
```

Then, in C:\Python27 I created "dbinsert.py":

```
import sqlite3 as db

conn = db.connect('test.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('insert into films values("Annie Hall","1977", "Woody Allen")')
cursor.execute('insert into films values("The Godfather","1972","Francis Ford Coppola")')
conn.close()
```

In cmd I ran it with "python dbinsert.py".
Then I entered "c:\sqlite\sqlite3 test.db".
Next "select * from films;".
Nothing happened while I thought cmd should list the info about films. What might be wrong here?

PS. At the moment I realised that I have Python27 and Python34 installed. Do you thing that might be a problem? If so, should I uninstall Python34?

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit your inserts. After execute you should call: conn.commit();

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you have any idea why in the tutorial everything worked even though the guy didn't include conn.commit(); ? Is it because he uses SQlite 3.7.10 and I use 3.8.6?